# How bad do your teaching evaluation scores have to be before you should leave them off your resume?

Tags: teaching, evaluation-criteria, course-evaluation

I got a 4.0 out of 5.0 on my teaching evaluations.  The average grade in my department is a 4.5.  Should I put this on my CV/resume?

For reference, I am a PhD student and this is the first class I've taught.

Comment: 4 out of 5 is nothing to scoff at. Whether the people who'd read your CV care about this number at all is another question...

Comment: It depends what kind of job you are applying for and in what field. It is important to realise that most of the high-rep users of this site are American scientists working in research universities. Maybe you are a literature student who is aiming for a job in a liberal arts college? In which case, the conventions might be different. In my experience, 4/5 would be very good in a mathematics dept but fairly mediocre in liberal arts. Whether you should mention it on your CV at all is doubtful, but you could include it in a teaching dossier.

Answer (score 39):

In my experience, people don't generally put teaching evaluation scores on a CV at all, regardless of what they are.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44287/discussion-on-answer-by-nate-eldredge-how-bad-do-your-teaching-evaluation-scores).